# I have a Custom ListView with an ImageView and TextView?

Tags: android, listview

I have custom ListView with an Image of Right Sign.

What I want is that whenever I click on any list row the sign of Right (Image) is occur on the clicked list row and remove that right sign (Image)from the previous row LIKE  radio button?
What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a custom Adapter
2. Maintain the current selected position as a instance variable  of the adapter
3. In getView, toggle your image view accordingly based on the current selected position.
4. And finally, in the OnItemClickListener of your listview, set the current selected position variable of the adapter with the current selected position.

Comment: In getView , how can use the 3rd point ? I didn't get the proper mean of this

Comment: I can get the position of the clicked row but in OnItemClickListener , when i reset the image on the row first row (Index [0]) changed everytime ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by storing flag (boolean) variable for each of the item you set with listview.

Than change the flag to true  of the item that is clicked .
Use listview.notifyDatasetChange() in onItemClick() so that listview get effect.

Comment: i'll try to do this and let you know about this